# How can I pair a new Apple mouse with my Mac?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

My Desktop Mac will not connect to my new Apple bluetooth mouse. I have bluetooth enabled on my Mac but I cannot get the mouse to pair. The mouse does not seem to have a pairing button that I can push.

I don't know how to find a manual or how to pair this - can someone describe the process?

Comment: Which Mac model? OS? Mouse model? Please [edit] your question to include these and any other details that could help arrive at a solution. Help us, help you.

Comment: If this is a Magic Mouse, connect the lightning cable between the mouse and the computer.

Comment: This will be closed as off topic / lacking details  if it's not an Apple mouse without more details - so let's assume Apple and let the OP write a new question if the answer / question isn't what they have for their setup.

Answer (score 2):

For Apple Magic Mouse, Magic Keyboard, and Magic Trackpad, the devices can be force-paired by connecting the included lightning cable to the computer and device.

Connect the cable and verify the connection is active by interacting with the keyboard or trackpad (This step cannot be done on the mouse). **It should work immediately**. Then, disconnect the cable. The bluetooth connection will take over. This should also happen immediately.